# List slicing in python every other value

Tags: python, slice

Suppose I have a list x = [1,2,3] and I want to output every other value than the indexed one, is there a list operation I can use?, ie: x[0]=> [2,3], x[1] => [1,3], x[2] =>[1,2] ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use this:

```
def exclude(l, e):
  return [v for i, v in enumerate(l) if i != e]

>>> exclude(range(10), 3)
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: +1.  This might be faster than the slicing methods because it doesn't create and throw away two intermediate lists.  Btw, good choice of function name.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - Thanks!  The internal variable names are kind of short, but for a quick write-out it seemed OK.

Comment: Can we use `!=` instead of `<>` though please :)

Comment: @JonClements - Sure, works for me.  Sorry, force of habit from SQL days.

Comment: @g.d.d.c It's been removed in 3.x. Anyway, +1, this is a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it with a slice, but I'd be tempted to try:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a[:]
del b[1]
```

**edit**

The above does "technically" use a slice operation, which happens to be on `list` objects in effect a shallow-copy.

What's more flexible and shouldn't have any downsides is to use:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(a)
del b[1]
```

The list builtin works on any iterable (while the slice operation `[:]` works on lists or those that are indexable) so that you could even extend it to constructs such as:

```
>>> a = '123'
>>> b = list(a)
>>> del b[0]
>>> ''.join(b)
'23'
```

Comment: I think this is the most sensible option, to be honest. It's extremely clear what is happening and massively simple.

Comment: This is technically also using a slice the way you have written it.

Comment: @MarkByers You could easily copy the list with `list(a)` if you wanted (which I actually feel is the nicer method of copying).

Comment: @Lattyware I'm trying to find it, but I vaguely remember discussions on c.l.p or something, that while `list(something)` works for arbitrary sequences (which is great) to copy a list is better using `something[:]` - will post if I find it

Comment: @JonClements Yes, it will do as `list(something)` takes any iterable and produces a list from it, while `something[:]` requires the iterable is a sequence that supports slicing. Another reason why I'd argue it's a better method of shallow copying.

Comment: @Lattyware: The slicing operation could potentially be more efficient. Anyway I'm not saying that it's a bad idea to use a slice, I just think it's misleading to write "You could do it with a slice, but" because this implies that no slice will be used, but on line 2 there's a slice.

Comment: @MarkByers okay, but we all know it's not really a slice, but rather a copy operation... I'm open to suggestions to amend post to make things clearer

Comment: @MarkByers As always, I would argue readability and clarity is preferable to speed unless it's a proven problem, so for normal copying, I would say use `list(blah)` - as an observation, I see a lot of duplicate questions on what `blah[:]` does that show it's not really that readable.

Comment: @Lattyware no more or less readable than `a, = some_function_returns_one_element_in_a_tuple()` I guess...

Comment: @JonClements No, but there is a valid alternative in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `x[:i] + x[i+1:]`:

```
In [8]: x = [1, 2, 3]

In [9]: i = 0

In [10]: x[:i] + x[i+1:]
Out[10]: [2, 3]
```

Depending on the context, `x.pop(i)` might also be useful. It modifies the list in place by removing and returning the `i-th` element. If you don't need the element, `del x[i]` is also an option.

Comment: `x.pop(i)` returns the element, if you don't need that, then just use `del x[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x[:1] + x[2:]
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list  = [1, 2, 3]
my_list.remove(my_list[_index_]) #_index_ is the index you want to remove
```

Such that: `my_list.remove(my_list[0])` would yield `[2, 3]`,
`my_list.remove(my_list[1])` would yield `[0, 3]`, and
`my_list.remove(my_list[2])` would yield `[1, 2]`.

Comment: Edit: I see now what you are trying to say, this is incorrect if there are duplicate values, and it affects the list in-place.

Answer (score -2):

So you want every value except the indexed value:
Where i is the index:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> [x for x in list if not x == list[i]]
```

This will give you a list with no instances of the i't element, so e.g.:

```
>>> i = 2
>>> list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> [x for x in list if not x == list[i]]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

note how 3 is not in that list at all.

Comment: See my comment on the other down-voted answer on this question.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the actual intent of the question.

Comment: This still isn't right, because it fails when the list has repeated elements.

Comment: This was as intended, added this now.

Comment: He asked how to exclude an index, not a value.

Comment: No, it clearly states "every other value than the indexed one"

Comment: The question is ambiguous, but I feel this is the far less likely scenario.

Answer (score -3):

Every other is

```
x[::2], start at 0
x[1::2], start at 1
```

Comment: The question is not "every other" as in step, the question is "all other values except the provided index".

Comment: I almost posted this answer too haha.

Comment: My bad, guess I shouldn't answer questions while tending kitchen.